# Uribuilder encoding with exclamation mark

Tags: java, jax-rs, url-encoding

I'm trying to use Uribuilder from:

```
javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
```

To update a URI.  The issue is that the parameter name gets escaped when I use replaceQueryParam.

so:

```
UriBuilder uriBuilder = webResource.getUriBuilder().
            replaceQueryParam("abcd!dcv, "wid").
            replaceQueryParam("format", "json");
```

if there is already an existing "abcd!dcv" parameter in the Uribuilder, it will escape and add a new one.  so it will become

```
?abcd!dcv=originalvalue&abcd%21cdv=wid
```

instead of

```
?abcd!dcv=wid
```

How should I get around this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`URIBuilder` is an abstract class and the implementation gets to decide which characters need special encoding and which do not. The `URIBuilder`  we get from a WebResource is attempting to follow the guidelines of [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). On page 12, **!** is listed as a sub-delimiter and this is why it is getting encoded. From my reading of the RFC, I don't think we should be using ! as part of a query parameter. For instance, Vaading uses ! to distinguish between sub-windows of the same application.

The simplest work around I can think of is to simply not use URIBuilder or use the fromURI method that takes a String as input. You can create the URI with everything except the part with the characters we don't want encoded, convert this to `astring`, manipulate `astring` to replace the query parameter and then call `URIBuilder.fromURI(aString)`